# What is the Fix for "UnapprovedUsageException: script not yet approved for use"

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, build-error

Note:Jenkins team not sure which method to approve and we found this tag to cloud-dojo and jenkins.

ERROR: script returned exit code 1

org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.UnapprovedUsageException: script not yet approved for use

```
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval.using(ScriptApproval.java:474)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval$using$0.call(Unknown Source)

    at com.splunk.splunkjenkins.UserActionDSL.perform(UserActionDSL.groovy:39)

    at com.splunk.splunkjenkins.listeners.LoggingRunListener.onCompleted(LoggingRunListener.java:85)

    at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireCompleted(RunListener.java:208)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.finish(WorkflowRun.java:625)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.access$800(WorkflowRun.java:138)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$GraphL.onNewHead(WorkflowRun.java:1045)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.notifyListeners(CpsFlowExecution.java:1473)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$3.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:491)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.run(CpsVmExecutorService.java:38)

    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)

    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)

    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Comment: If you can't see the Script in: Manage Jenkins > Script Approval menu, you can try to visit Manage Jenkins > System Log > All Jenkins Logs. You can see additional information in there